# Eclipse RCP: add scrollable text in a MessageDialog?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am very new to Eclipse RCP.

I have a message dialog as follows:

```java
MessageDialog.openConfirm(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell(),
                            ProcessingResources.getLabel("DeleteProcessCommand.deleteProcessTitle"),
                            ProcessingResources.getLabel("DeleteProcessCommand.deleteProcessText",
                            myString);
```

However, the variable `myString` can be very long and can cause the window to take up the whole screen.

Is there a way of making just that message scrollable?

I looked into `ScrolledComposite` but the `MessageDialog` function needs a string input, not a composite.

Comment: You can't do that using the static methods like `openConfirm`. You can create a new dialog extending `MessageDialog` and overriding the `createMessageArea` method.